# Legend not printed on ggplot graph, code with error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot proper graph with lable, title and legend. here is my attempt to produce legend. but why this error comeout. is there extra package I missed to load? [Details on my data available here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52622314/7356308) . Kindly help.. Thank you

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
geom_line(data = Press_1000, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "darkblue") +
geom_line(data = Press_925, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "red") +
scale_color_discrete(name = "Pressure Level", labels = c( "1000", "925"))
#graph plotted without legend 

ggplot() + 
geom_line(data = Press_1000, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "Y1") +
geom_line(data = Press_925, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "Y2") + 
scale_color_manual(values = c('Y1' = 'darkblue','Y2' = 'red')) +
labs(color = "Pressure Level")
#Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'Y1'

ggplot() + 
geom_line(data = Press_1000, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "a") +
geom_line(data = Press_925, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c), color = "b") + 
scale_color_manual(name = "Colors", values = c("a" = "blue", "b" = "red"))
#Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : invalid color name 'a'
```

Comment: You need to put the color = ... inside aes.

Comment: You should provide enough information for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523) so that others can reproduce your problem. But as Roland pointed out, place your color within `aes` rather than outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Roland, you have to use `aes(...)` to solve this.

Using your first example, the problem is that you need to define the color variable in the `aes(...)` part to get fixed levels:

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = Press_1000, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c, color = "a")) +
    geom_line(data = Press_925, aes(as.Date(date), temp_c, color = "b")) +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Pressure Level", labels = c( "1000", "925"))
```

Then your color scale will have two level "a" and "b".
Because you "force" them to be "a" and "b". You can afterwards change their color using the `values = ...` argument in the `scale_color_discrete()` function to change its color.

When the color are defined **outside** `aes(...)` they are fixed manually. Thus only R color values are tolerated by `ggplot2`. When they are defined using strings **inside** `aes(...)` they are considered as **categories** and can further be used in the `scale_color_...()` function.